# Folder access is not allowed

Tags: vb.net

I have written a program in VB where some attachments from an email are stored in the computer, programatically.

The process of saving the files is this:

1. Creates a temporary folder and save the attachment there. 
   "C:\tempFolder\attachment.fletyp"
2. This file is analyzed and then save to its corresponding folder, say "C:\AnotherFolder\attachment.fletyp"
3. After saving the file, it will set the file's lastWriteTime property according to when the mail was sent.
4. "C:\AnotherFolder"s lastwritetime is also changed.
5. Delete all from "C:\tempFolder"

Sometimes, it works fine. But there are times when bug suddenly occurs, the error message is:

> The process cannot access the file "C:\AnotherFolder" because it is being used by another process.

*Notice that it is the folder, not the file, that the program cannot access.*

My guess is that it happens first on step 3, when the program is still "writing" on the file's lastwritetime and is not yet "released" when step 4 happens.

I'm having trouble on replicating the error because "it just happens".

My question is how can I tell if the folder itself is still under a process, wait for it to finish and then write to it again?

**EDIT**

I have narrowed down the problem by testing out this code which produces the same error. I don't know if this is the case, but there's I think a 90% chance that it is.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 500
    Try
        Directory.SetLastWriteTime("C:\anotherFolder", Date.Now)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Console.WriteLine(i)
Next
```

In my case, the email has 6 attachments. (I just made it to 500 so that the exception would  occur easily). Everytime the attachment is saved, it will write the lastWriteTime into its parent folder. Try running the code again if the exception does not happen.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Dim path As String = "C:\anotherFolder"
```

---

and

```
Directory.SetLastWriteTime(path, DateTime.Now)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response sir.. but still the same output :(

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setlastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1